# Print char pointer char array with printf?

Tags: arrays, pointers, character, printf

I'm trying to print the whole word instead of just the first letter. I could do it with a loop but I figured there was a better way. I was searching around and saw answers that they changed %S to %c but I'm already using %c since it's a character array.

```
char* words[] = {"my", "word", "list"};
printf("The word: %c",*words[2]);

Results:
The word: l
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `%s`, a format used specifically for null-terminated arrays of characters (i.e. C strings). You do not dereference the array's element when you pass it to `printf`, like this:

```
printf("The word: %s\n", words[2]);
```

Comment: I must have read the code wrong when I did my search I did have %S but as you can see I used uppercase. I was getting random characters which I figured it was displaying from the address which is why I double derefferenced it. Removed that and changed it to s now everything works. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that you dereferenced twice.  The [2] in *words[2] dereferences from words[] to "list" then the * dereferences a second time from "list" to 'l'  Remove the * and voila.

```
char* words[] = {"my", "word", "list"};
printf("The word: %s", words[2]);
```

Comment: Ah I see, I was wondering about the dereferencing but I was getting random characters if I didn't before when I was using %S I might have read the lowercase as an upper case. Thank you that solved it.